# Convertir mail a PDF adjunto

Tags: php, html, pdf, mail

tengo un mail que me llega con una orden de visita la cual está en HTML y se muestra como un body normal al llegar al correo del cliente. Cada orden es única ya que trae datos dependiendo el agendamiento. Este HTML que se me muestra en el correo, quiero que se transforme y se adjunte como PDF, he intentado de todo y no logro hacer que funcione.

Este es el inicio:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$to = $_POST['to'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$uf = number_format($_POST['uf'], 0, '.', '.');
$baths = $_POST['baths'];
$rooms = $_POST['rooms'];
$meters = $_POST['meters'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$terraza = $_POST['terraza'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

$schedule = $_POST['schedule'];

$link = 'https://......=';
$url = $link . $schedule;
$rut = $_POST['rut'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$html =
```

Y el final:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->charSet = "UTF-8";
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = '';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = '';
    $mail->Password   = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = ;
    $mail->setFrom('');
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->addBCC('');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Prueba PDF";
    $mail->Body = $html;
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function adjuntarPdf($html)
 {
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('html');
    //path es la ruta donde quieres que se almacene tu pdf
    $render_pdf = $path.'/pdf_adjunto.pdf';
    $mpdf->Output($render_pdf, "F");
    return render_pdf;
 }

 //dentro de tu codifo de envio
 $mail->AddAttachment(adjuntarPdf($tuformulario),"adjunto.pdf");
```

> No olvides de incluir la libreria de MPDF, ya no se. Si sea correcto escribir nuevamente el enlace. ~~!

Comment: El public se incluye en que parte? Luego de cerrar el HTML?

Comment: en tu caso creo que no necesitas usar el public. Agrega el fragmento de codigo antes que envíes el adjunto.